# Import .sql file using ssh

Tags: mysql, sql, import, ssh, phpmyadmin

I read many tutorials online on how to import sql scripts using ssh, and that is `mysql –u [username] –p [database] < [file_name].sql` but only works for single database. I created an sql file of my localhost (all databases), I did this using PhpMyAdmin and tried to use the code of importing but nothing happens.

Is there a separate way on how to do this?

Comment: have you tried simple import/export from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't specify the `--one-database` arg, there's nothing preventing you from adding a `USE <some-other-db>;` statement as necessary within your `.sql` file.

Comment: Can you show me the new code? I tried this `mysql -u user -p localhost.sql` but I receive again the manual for MySQL usage.

Answer (score 1):

mysql -h localhost -u root -p -e "source d:\test.sql"

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'localhost.sql' at line 1.

Comment: Im using windows server, check your \ and change it for the correct path to localhost.sql which version of MySQL server are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm using Linux but the path isn't the problem.

Comment: It should work, its using MySQL in batch mode [Check this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html) for more information.